# Hello World Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make a simple dialog box showing my name. Look at the code.

```
Pessoa *p = new Pessoa("Ronald Araújo", "ronald.araujo@live.com", 23);

QMessageBox msg; msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8(p->getNome()));
msg.exec();
```

But the code breaks in the line of setText () with the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QString::fromUtf8(std::string)'
msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8(p->getNome));
```

Remembering that when I put for example `msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8("Hi World"))` the code runs normally.

Implementation to return the name:

```
string Pessoa::getNome(){ return this->nome; }
```

Comment: `Pessoa::getNome()` should return `QString` instead of `std::string`. By the way you should be consistent and use English as your language for programming rather than Portuguese. One more remark: When you work with Qt, try to avoid mixing Qt containers/types/etc. with STL and stick to the Qt versions. This will avoid many problems and improve your code readability/consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QString`s can't be constructed from `std::string` directly.  You have two options that I can think of immediately:

Either change

```
string Pessoa::getNome(){ return this->nome; }
```

to

```
QString Pessoa::getNome(){ return this->nome; }
```

or change

```
 QMessageBox msg;
 msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8(p->getNome()));
 msg.exec();
```

to

```
QMessageBox msg;
msg.setText(QString::fromUtf8(QString::fromStdString(p->getNome())));
msg.exec();
```

Comment: You must also modify the constructor? It gave error that your suggestion...
Pessoa::Pessoa(string nome, string email, int idade){
  this->nome = nome;
  this->email = email;
  this->idade = idade;
}

Comment: Yes, you would need to change nome to be a QString also.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation of [`QString::fromUtf8()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8):

```
QString QString::fromUtf8( const char * str, int size = -1 )
```

It does not take a `std::string` as its first argument. You can either use [`QString::fromStdString()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromStdString)

```
QString QString::fromStdString( const std::string & str )
```

which does take an `std::string`, or change your code to provide the `char array` of the string:

```
msg.setText( QString::fromUtf8( p->getNome().c_str() ) );
```

Comment: You must also modify the constructor? It gave error that your suggestion...
Pessoa::Pessoa(string nome, string email, int idade){
  this->nome = nome;
  this->email = email;
  this->idade = idade;
}

Comment: @RonaldAraújo That seems like a different error to me. You wanted to convert a `std::string` to a `QString` with utf8 conversion, so that is what I solved in the answer. And unless you give us the exact error message, we can't possibly know what you're talking about.